# Is this really an expansion issue?

Tags: batch-processing

In a batch file, this works:

```
@echo off
:start
set /p field3=
cls
echo checking field 3
goto %field3%

:a
echo field3 is a
goto start

:b
echo field3 is b
goto start

:c
echo field 3 is c
goto start
```

However this does not:

```
@echo off
:start
set /p field3=
cls
echo checking field 3
if "%field3%"=="" goto start else goto %field3%
REM goto %field3%

:a
echo field3 is a
goto start

:b
echo field3 is b
goto start

:c
echo field 3 is c
goto start
```

In the last example field3 stays constant and does not change. As I understand it, without delayed expansion, field3 will stay constant, not change when the line is parsed in the "if" statment. But why does it work with `goto %field3%`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I discovered my error. In an "If" statement, at least in a batch file, the following commands need to be separated otherwise they are read as a whole. So `if "%field3%"=="" goto start else goto %field3%` needs to be `if "%field3%"=="" (goto start) else goto %field3%`. This is well documented all over the place and I simply failed to catch it.